# How to build correct WAR file from switchyard project with Maven

Tags: java, web-services, jboss

The problems I face:

I need to build `*.war` with Maven from Switchyard project to deploy war, not jar as usual. And as I understand, *.war is also acceptable to make Switchyard work. But when I build war, no Switchyard services available though everything is deployed successfully on JBoss.

How to do that? Is there any hints how to correctly assemble war for Switchyard?

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the answer.
Unfortunately there is no instruction how to build correct WAR for Switchyard project, so I hope my experience will help some day to some people.
All that you need is to move both switchyard.xml and beans.xml from src/main/META-INF to src/main/webapp/WEB-INF and build WAR after that ( don't forget to add war to the pom.xml ).

That solved the problem, now Switchyard services are available (but not work).